# Accessing resources in a resources only .jar

Tags: java

I've created a .jar file that contains a single resource (XML) file and I've placed it in a folder specified in my application's classpath. In my code (within a class in a different jar) I can build a `URLClassLoader` object with the 'resource' jar's URL but it looks to be empty (no packages, no classes).

I know how to access resources from a .jar using `getResourceXXX`methods but  I'm obtaining `null`. I can get the classloader for the .jar where the resource is, but the resource seems to not be loaded.

My question is: is that jar loaded if it doesn't hold any .class file? Is there any way to access resources in that jar?

Comment: Can you show you codes, I don't see any problem using the `getResourceAsStream` in getting resources from `jar`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will be loaded.  You would access the resources just as usual by calling `getResourceAsStream` or `findResource`